# ggplot wrap command text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started to work with `ggplot2` package and I encountered a problem.

When I type in .R file:

```
barGG <- ggplot(data4,aes(date,base), colour = factor(operator)) 
barGG + geom_point(aes(color = operator)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = operator),method = loess, size = 1) + facet_grid(. ~ city) + ggtitle("Operators TOM by city") + scale_colour_manual(values = cols) + myTheme
```

everything works but if I type same commands in separate lines:

```
barGG + geom_point(aes(color = operator)) 
      + geom_smooth(aes(color = operator),method = loess, size = 1) 
      + facet_grid(. ~ city) + ggtitle("Operators TOM by city") 
      + scale_colour_manual(values = cols) 
      + myTheme
```

only first line is executed. 
I use R version 3.0.3, Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) and the R-studio Version 0.98.501

Comment: You need to put the `+` at the end of each line, not the start.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the `+` after the lines, not before the next line. If you do not add the `+` at the end, R thinks your statement is done and will no longer look for any next lines. Adding the `+` at the end, triggers R to continue adding the next lines to the statement.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But why? When I used ggsave command it didn't matter.

Comment: This is how R syntax works, if the statement is done, the interpreter does not look at the next lines anymore. Furthermore, `ggsave` is a separate command, and not part of the `ggplot` object you build.

Comment: @BiXiC `ggsave` saves the last plot, not what you think you're drawing. Is it possible that have had a plotted figure in the background?